# A property of 47 with respect to partitions into five parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions

Is 47 the largest number which has a unique partition into five parts (15, 10, 10, 6, 6), no two of which are relatively prime?

Comment: If $n$ has a factor between $2$ and $n/6$, then there are at least two such partitions, hence for $n\geq 36$ we only need to look at primes.

Comment: Was this question inspired by the recent puzzling.SE question [My five daughters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58287/40625)? Edit: Oh, you're the same guy!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $n>47$.

If $2\mid n$, we can take $(n-8,2,2,2,2),(n-10,4,2,2,2)$, which are distinct partitions for $n\geq 14$.

If $3\mid n$, we can take $(n-12,3,3,3,3),(n-15,6,3,3,3)$, which are distinct partitions for $n\geq 21$.

If $n\equiv 1\pmod 6$, we can take $(n-37,15,10,6,6),(n-43,15,12,10,6)$, which are distinct partitions for $n\geq 55$, and $(21,7,7,7,7),(14,14,7,7,7)$ for $n=49$.

If $n\equiv 5\pmod 6$, we can take $(n-41,15,10,10,6),(n-47,15,12,10,10)$, which are distinct partitions for $n\geq 59$, and $(20,15,6,6,6),(15,12,10,10,6)$ for $n=53$.

(Thanks to Gerhard for pointing out we can finish the argument quickly from what I wrote before)

Comment: Once you fix n-42 to n-43, your construction produces partitions for n greater than 53, and only 49 is not covered by the remaining cases, but is covered by your comment above.  Care to finish off the problem?  Gerhard "Solved It By That Much" Paseman, 2017.12.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Sure enough! I didn't quite realize the few different constructions have different bounds for when they are valid, so they do rule out most of the cases. Als, thanks for spotting the typo.

Comment: Hint: 21 14 6 6 6 .  Gerhard "Putting The Cherry On Top" Paseman, 2017.12.22.

Comment: Indeed.  And (15, 10, 6, 6, 6) shows that we can't do much for primes below 43 (assuming positive partition members).  Gerhard "Let Us Add Some Sprinkles" Paseman, 2017.12.22.

Comment: Appending another $6$ solves the general problem for $k \ge 5$ parts: any solution must be less than 29 + $6 \cdot k$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick demonstration that it is effectively solvable for any number of parts.

A sufficiently large number that has exactly one partition with the property must be prime.  Otherwise we can write it as $n = a \cdot b$ with $1 < a \leq b$ and partition $b$ into $k$ parts in two different ways, then multiply them by $a$ to get two different partitions of $n$ with the property.

Now suppose $n = 6 \cdot m + 35$.  A sufficiently large $m$ has two different partitions into $k - 1$ parts such that each part of each partition is divisible by either $5$ or $7$.  Multiplying by $6$ and appending $35$ then gives two different partitions of $n$ with the property.

On the other hand, suppose $n = 6 \cdot m + 55 = 6 \cdot m + 5 \cdot 11$.  The same logic above applies, and that covers all the cases.  Filling in some more details results in a simple formula for an upper bound in terms of $k$: the first part says if $n$ is composite then $n \lt (k+2)^2$, and the second part chases down the primes relatively more quickly placing the largest one in $6 \cdot k + O(1)$.

More generally still, we can require that the pairwise $\text{gcd}$ of the parts be greater than or equal to some $d \ge 2$ (so the question of $47$ corresponds to the case $d = 2$ and $k = 5$).  An effective upper bound on unique solutions can still be obtained: we just have to carry out the above argument for all congruence classes mod $d$, in each case representing the remainder as a semiprime with prime factors larger than $d$.

EDIT: That led me to the following even simpler version, working mod $2$ instead of mod $6$: if $m$ has two different partitions into $5$ parts, then $n = 2 \cdot m$ has two different partitions into $5$ parts, no two parts of which are relatively prime.  So $n < 2 \cdot (5+2) = 14$ if $n$ is even.  Otherwise, suppose $n = 2 \cdot m + 15$, and observe that

$18 = 3+3+6+6 = 3+3+3+9$,

$19 = 3+5+5+6 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 10$, and

$20 = 3+3+5+9 = 3+5+6+6$

to conclude $m \le 17$ and $n \le 49$.